# Function to calculate number of loans done in the previous year for SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Library loans table which records the LoanID, OutDate, DueDate, and InDate for each book loan. I want to create a function that will accept the previous year (ex. 2017) as input and output the number of loans for that year by counting the loan ids. I am able to do this but the number is repeated multiple times in the result set and I only want it to return one value.

```
create function Books.numLoansLastYear
(
    @year as int
)
returns int
as
    begin
        declare @numLoans as int
        select @numLoans = COUNT(LoanID) 
            from Reservations.Loan
            where year(OutDate) = @year
        return @numLoans
    end
;
go
```

To test I am using the following query:

```
select Books.numLoansLastYear(year(GETDATE())-1) as 'Number of Loans'
from Reservations.Loan
;
```

The only way that I am able to resolve this is by using **DISTINCT** in my test query so I am wondering if my function is incorrect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post sample data and your current output, please.  See [ask] and [mcve] for details.

Comment: A scalar function here is probably not the best. An inline table valued function would be better. But the question is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little unclear on your question.  If your query were:

```
select l.*
from Reservations.Loan l;
```

You would not be surprised at getting multiple rows.

The same is true if you select anything with `from` and no filtering (or other conditions).  You are selecting all the rows in the table.  This is true even for a function call or constant.

I think you simply want:

```
select Books.numLoansLastYear(year(GETDATE())-1) as [Number of Loans];
```

Note the lack of `from` clause.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The logic makes sense too.